# Categorey based product limit

Tags: php, wordpress, limit, objective-c-category

Can anyone help me with below Issue and how to solve the same.

There are Number of products in 2 categories (`CatA` & `CatB`),
`CatA` is having below products
`P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4`, `P5`
CatB is having below products,
`Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, `Q4`, `Q5`
i need to restrict below conditions.
If a customer is purchasing from `CatA`, only 1 product from `CatA` needs to be added no other product can be added from this category but customer can add “`N`” number of products from `CatB`.

For example,
I am a customer, i want to buy product from `CatA` i.e `P1` and added the same. now when i am selecting `P2` an error should be displayed and product `P2` should not be added in cart. but if i want to add `Q1` or `Q2` with `P1` i can able to add the same.

Is this possible.

I had tried using other plugins but it didnt worked Woocommerce Minimum and Maximum Quantity and Woocommerce Minimum and Maximum Quantity

Also tried with code,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_total' );
function check_total() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

        global $woocommerce, $product;

        $total_quantity = 0;
        $display_notice = 1;
        $i = 0;
        //loop through all cart products
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {

            // See if any product is from the cuvees category or not
            if ( has_term( 'category-1', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] )) {
                $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];
            }

        }
        // Set up the acceptable totals and loop through them so we don't have an ugly if statement below.
        $acceptable_totals = array(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy method would be  :

> Set a variable named $flag= false;

When the CAT A product is added to the cart or variable you set the variable

`$flag = true; //This means same type of product cannot be added.`

Thus inside `foreach` loop you can check `$flag` when CAT A Type product exist.

Comment: Can you please help me with writting a code for me.

Answer (score 0):

@AftabHusain and @RohanKumarShrestha
Are you stating like below.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_total' );
    function check_total() {
        // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
        if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $total_quantity = 0;
            $display_notice = 1;
            $i = 0;                                                                                           



    //loop through all cart products
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product  $flag = true; //This means same type of product cannot be added. ) {

        // See if any product is from the cuvees category or not
        if ( has_term( 'CatA', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] )) {
            $total_quantity += $product['1'];
        }

    }
    // Set up the acceptable totals and loop through them so we don't have an ugly if statement below.
    $acceptable_totals = array(1);
```

Like this you are saying?